# How to edit a json file by shell script to change the coordinate point , in which original points are divided by 2

Tags: json, shell

For Example : My original Json is

```
{
    "planetsQuestion":[
        {
            "state":"Andhra Pradesh",
            "capital":"Hyderabad",
            "point":["520","550"]
        },
 {
            "state":"Arunachal Pradesh",
            "capital":"Itanagar",
            "point":["886","294"]
        }
   ]
}

   // but i want this in same format
{
    "planetsQuestion":[
        {
            "state":"Andhra Pradesh",
            "capital":"Hyderabad",
            "point":["260","275"]
        },
 {
            "state":"Arunachal Pradesh",
            "capital":"Itanagar",
            "point":["443","147"]
        }
   ]
}
```

In which original points are divided by 2 and i used the jq shell command.

jq is like sed for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you play with text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell is an unsuitable tool to parse json and do math. In perl this is a one-liner:

```
$ perl -pe '/point/ && s,(\d+),$1/2,eg' inputfile
{
    "planetsQuestion":[
        {
            "state":"Andhra Pradesh",
            "capital":"Hyderabad",
            "point":["260","275"]
        },
 {
            "state":"Arunachal Pradesh",
            "capital":"Itanagar",
            "point":["443","147"]
        }
   ]
}
```